# Program exits when executing this loop outside of the IDE

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running into a weird issue where a simple dice roll program runs perfectly fine in vscode and pycharm but won't execute via terminal on any machines I've tried it on. I think the problem is one of these two loops, because the code makes it past the input stage.

```
    #Rolls the dice and fills the list with values
for i in range(numDice):
    diceTable.append(random.randint(1,sideDice))
    i += 1
#Sums all the values in the table together
for j in range(numDice):
   diceTotal = diceTotal + diceTable[j]
   j += 1
```

I have quadruple checked my assignation, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: How is `numDice` being assigned?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` and `j`? Thats fully redundant.

Comment: try `total = sum(diceTable)`

Comment: @joshmeranda I am assigning it as 0, and than an int(input("blahblah") to assign it as a new integer.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you try to execute outside of the IDE?

Comment: `"won't execute via terminal"` - Python code doesn't just "not execute" - there will be always an error message if something is wrong, so please add that to your post.

Comment: @Programmer It exits cleanly as soon as I finish with the user inputs.

Comment: @PatrickArtner It didn't solve the issue, but those are some helpful optimizations, thank you. I'm still learning python, obviously.

Comment: `from random import choices` + `dices = choices(range(1,sideDice+1), k = numDice)` + `print(sum(dices))` - your code is incomplete - read [ask] and [edit] it to a fully executeable example that reproduces your problem: [mre].

Comment: Hmm, and what did you input ?